# Bundler doesn't get installed properly

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, bundler, rbenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm just so lost. I set up Ubuntu on Windows and installed rbenv using `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash`. Added relevant lines to my .zshrc file, installed necessary ruby version, so now `ruby -v` command shows `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]` as it should. I ran `sudo gem install bundler` which printed nicely `Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1`. But when I run `bundler` command I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/michal-sadowski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
        1: from /home/michal-sadowski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/home/michal-sadowski/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundler (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

What can I do to get it run?

`which bundler` gives `/home/michal-sadowski/.rbenv/shims/bundler`
`which ruby` gives `/home/michal-sadowski/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Your should never ever use `sudo` in gem install command, you will probably break all your rbenv scripts.

Comment: Before that I also tried without `sudo`. Let me reinstall rbenv and try again.

Comment: @Зелёный it seems that it was partially this, partially because of ubuntu bundled ruby version which locked permissions to folders - and at the tip of the problem a mismatched version in my project's gemlock file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mix of issues.

1. I shouldn't have used `sudo`, very plausible that it broke some paths
2. I shouldn't have to use `sudo` in the first place - but installing ruby directly through `sudo apt install ruby-full` most likely set restrictive access to necessary folders
3. After uninstalling system default ruby version and reinstalling rbenv I could call `bundler` without an error - just not in the right folder. Turned out that the issue was a `gemlock` file that had a bundled with field set to 1.x, caused by one old gemfile. After removing the gemlock file and that dependency - it went more or less smoothly.

Comment: Argh, thank you! I had a similar problem after a ruby upgrade. Turns out the gemlock file with `bundler (>= 1.3.0)`
Removed the gemlock and re-tried `bundle install` all commenced working. Much appreciated!